# creating HTTPS client in NodeJS - ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

Tags: node.js

I created a http client using NodeJS as shown below:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost', 
    port: 8445, 
    path: 'authorisation/getIt', 
    method: 'GET', 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('root_cert.pem', 'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('consumer_private_key.pem', 'utf8'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('consumer_cert.pem', 'utf8'), 
    passphrase: 'password',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
 };

var request = new https.request(options, function(response) {
   response.on('data', function(chunk) {
       console.log("%s", chunk);
})
```

When I run this client against a server, I get the error

> Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match
>   certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not cert's CN:
>   LC_AAA_Server
>       at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:225:17)
>       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1046:27)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:127:13)
>       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)

If I change the hostname field to the text in CN of server certificate, the client gives an error

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND LC_AAA_Server

How can I change the hostname to match CN of server certificate but make the client still point to the server hosted on local host.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: Can't you generate another certificate with a different alt name?